# How to move user authentication permissions from django admin to html select input

Tags: python, django

How to move user authentication permissions from django admin to html select input

Cannot make status selectable from frontend

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <div class="container-fluid bg-light p-4">
  <div class="form-group" >
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group" >
      <label for="name">Surname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" placeholder="Enter Surname">
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select1">Select status</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="select1">
        <option>Supervisor</option>
        <option>Staff</option>
        <option>Active</option>
      </select>
   </div>

<button class="btn btn-success">Add new user</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your form url and view that you want you can't ask all stuff but raise question if you stuck on error so pls provide some code where you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) where you can find what attributes have the user model class.

For example, active is a boolean, same goes for staff. 
If you want to set the status of an user as active, you must use a check box in html.

**edit**
your are not providing enough code and  context to help you search for more details that can help you achieve what you need.